# Improperly formatted stripe checkout create action

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I spent a lot of time going back and forth changing my code and re-running `yarn run build` and then `bin/dev` but I keep getting syntax errors for this controller

```
class CheckoutsController < ApplicationController
  respond_to :js

    def create
          @session = Stripe::Checkout::Session.create({
            payment_method_types: ['card'],
            line_items: [{
                price_data: {
                product: "prod_Miva1sJtJ2u812",
                currency: 'usd',
                metadata:
                  {
                  post_id: params[:post_id],
                  },
               quantity: 1,
              }
                ]},
                mode: 'payment',
                success_url: "http://localhost:3000",
                cancel_url: "http://localhost:3000",
              })
              respond_to do |format|
                format.js
              end
    end
end
```

Answer (score 0):

It looks like the closing brace and closing bracket are swapped. Try this:

```rb
def create
  @session = Stripe::Checkout::Session.create({
    payment_method_types: ['card'],
    line_items: [{
      price_data: {
        product: 'prod_Miva1sJtJ2u812',
        currency: 'usd',
        metadata:
          {
            post_id: params[:post_id]
          }
      },
      quantity: 1 # <-- quantity should be under the line item instead of price_data
    }],  # <-- these two were flipped
    mode: 'payment',
    success_url: 'http://localhost:3000',
    cancel_url: 'http://localhost:3000'
  })
  respond_to do |format|
    format.js
  end
end
```

Comment: 11:28:30 web.1  | Stripe::InvalidRequestError (Received unknown parameter: line_items[0][price_data][quantity]):

Comment: Looking at the Stripe docs (https://stripe.com/docs/api/checkout/sessions/create?lang=ruby#create_checkout_session-line_items-quantity), I think quantity needs to be under `line_items` not `price_data`

Comment: I just updated the answer to move the quantity, can you give that a try and lmk how it goes?